# What is the typical maximum Bluetooth MTU size in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on an Android app that communicates with a device via Bluetooth (BLE).

I know that the device can support MTU sizes up to 240 bytes. And when I connect to it with my app, I always get an MTU of 240 bytes after the negotiation completes.

Generally speaking, my app has simple functions that send or receive less than 15 bytes of data, and it also has one function that can transfer large files by breaking them up into blocks that match the MTU size.

I have a new "simple" function that actually needs to send 50 bytes of data. I know that I could potentially break it up into multiple packets in the event the MTU size is less than 50, but it would be extremely convenient for me not to do this, if I could count on the MTU always being over 50.

Is this a reasonable assumption to make, assuming I want my app to work with the majority of late-model Android devices?

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

I've seen 517 being commonly used. That way a single characteristic value (max size allowed by the standard is 512 bytes) can be sent in all common kinds of ATT packets.

In a few cases a larger MTU can be good to have if you use procedures that send multiple values at once.

The only reason I can think of when you want to have a small MTU is when you have a device with tiny amounts of RAM where it is not possible to buffer up that much data.